# Upgrade to SSD without Re-installing OS

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ssd

I have a MacBook Pro with a 750 GB HDD and am planning to upgrade to a 240 GB SSD.

I know with Windows if you have 2 hard drives you can do a sector by sector copy if your new drive is larger than your old drive.

Is there a way to clone the ~150 GB of files + OS I have on the HDD to the SSD so I don't have to re-install the OS and configure everything again?

Comment: Can't you shrink the system partition to ~240GB and do a sector-by-sector copy?

Comment: @techie007 Not a duplicate because in that question the new SSD is *larger*. Here the SSD is smaller.

Comment: Ahh, then check these: http://superuser.com/questions/285457/clone-hard-drive-to-another-smaller-hard-drive, http://superuser.com/questions/114003/can-you-clone-a-larger-drive-onto-a-smaller-drive-used-space-fits-on-the-smalle, http://superuser.com/questions/287171/how-can-i-transfer-windows-from-a-partition-of-an-existing-hard-drive-to-a-new

Comment: @techie007 The previous questions that you refer to as being duplicates are not Mac specific.

Comment: @techie007: More importantly, none of the proposed duplicates deal with the HFS+ (aka Mac OS X Extended) volume format

Comment: Many of those answers point to using two tools. One to shrink the existing partition, and one to clone it.  Clonezilla is HFS+ compatible, and GPartEd can be run from a HFS+-Enabled Linux install/LiveCD. There are other Apple disk utilities that can help with the resizing as well.  In your question you haven't stated what you've tried already, or where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use Carbon Copy Cloner or SuperDuper and clone your 750GB HDD to the 240GB SSD. You could also shrink the partition size using GParted, however before shrinking the partition size make sure you have a backup of your data.

---

**Carbon Copy Cloner:**
[bombich.com](http://bombich.com)

**SuperDuper:**
[shirt-pocket.com/superduper](http://shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper)