# How to clone the complete HDD except of one big Partition to a smaller hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, clone

I have to replace a 250GB HDD with a 128GB HDD. There is a boot-loader partition witch loads several OS on other partitions. There is also a 140GB partition with important but not needed data on it. At least I am not able to temporarily backup this data elsewhere.

I tried several clone-tools like clonezilla. But I found none which would be able to clone a bigger HDD to a smaller HDD if I don't want to clone every partition.

Last but not least, I am not able to shut down the system for longer then 3 hours, hopefully this is enough for 110GB...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone a Hard Drive to a slightly smaller Hard Drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/88173/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-to-a-slightly-smaller-hard-drive), [Clone hard drive to another, smaller hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/285457/clone-hard-drive-to-another-smaller-hard-drive?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007:  The second question links to the first as a duplicate and contains a number of additional answers.  Seems like it would be more helpful to use it as the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Clone it to a third drive that's bigger than 250GB, delete the partition you don't want, then clone it to your 140GB one.

As for how long it'll take, there are a lot of factors that make it impossible to tell you. [If you can transfer at 40 MB/s](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/678783-What-are-the-standart-write-read-speeds-for-sata-HDD) then you'll clone the 250GB drive in 1:45 and then the 140GB drive in 58 minutes. That gives you 15 minutes for deleting the partition and setting everything up to still be under 3 hours.

Comment: It would be no problem to solve this with an third drive, but I need to find a way to do this without a third drive. I'm not really worried about the 3 hours, if I'm not able to complete the setup I'm able to finish it at the next night.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu, you can use the [disk utility](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/) to do this. You can use it to copy the partitions you do want to keep to the smaller hard drive.[image]

Comment: Nice hint, I will look about it, thx. Maybe there is something to find in this debian distro

Answer (score 0):

If the data fits on the smaller disk you can clone it with free Macrium. But in your case it may be better to use images and just uncheck the partition(s) you do not want during the imaging setup. Here is a Macrium tutorial I made that may help:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I

And if you don't have a third disk for the images, make a free partition on the 500GB drive to store the images. You can take and restore the partitions one after another.